# how to sync between two folders in chef

Tags: chef-infra

How to sync between two folders which are present on the same server. Generally in shell am using the "rsync" command for this action.

AM new to CHEF, could you please suggest me, is there any resource for rsync or sync between two folders.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, what you want to achieve with rsync on same server.

Though, you can leverage the "rsync cookbook" and call its LWRPs as resources.

Supermarket

```
https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/rsync
```

Github

```
https://github.com/chef-cookbooks/rsync
```

Answer (score 0):

Chef doesn't offer anything for this specifically, you would generally use `cp` or `rsync` in an `execute` resource but this can be difficult to make idempotent and fully convergent. You could implement it in pure Ruby if you wanted to, but it would be a lot more difficult.